# Any way to programatically execute a Managed notebooks inside GCP Vertex AI workbench?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sdk, workbench, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to programmatically execute a notebook inside a [Workbench](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai-workbench) instance from GCP Vertex AI.

I can't find any API or SDK to do it... event the [Vertex AI SDK](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/index.html?highlight=vertex) for Python does not have access to the workbench.

Not sure if I am missing the correct documentation? or if they don't provide any way to execute Managed notebooks programmatically.

My goal is to add a function to my python data pipeline to execute this notebook remotely.

Comment: are you trying to execute a different notebook inside workbench instance?

Comment: Can also... I want to use a microservice to execute a notebook inside a workbench instance. from a different notebook in the same instance, or from a totally different instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Vertex Google managed instance it should come with a the Executor extension. And in case you are using a User managed instance you can download that same extension.
Link of googles documentation about the functionality:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/executor

Comment: As of now, you can't call the executor API programmatically... so this option is not what I am looking for.